# Что делать если испортил проект андроид

Tags: android-studio

Мне нужно было сделать элементы пролистываемыми, для чего я их поместил в scrollview, но потом передумал. Начал из scrollview вытаскивать всё обратно на linearlayout, но по какой то причине они перемещаться не хотели. Тогда я удалил scrollview в текстовом редакторе xml (то есть текст, относящийся к элементам, остался в коде). Неужели никак не отменить все эти действия? Потому что любое изменение в проекте android studio автоматически сохраняет. А ctrl + z не помогает в данной ситуации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще стоит использовать систему контроля версий, например Git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте необходимый файл, далее в верхнем меню выберите VCS -> Local History -> Show History. Там выберите необходимую версию для восстановления.